# How to use Word2vec in an Angular Application

Tags: javascript, python, angular, nlp, word2vec

I have an Angular application that allows users to post some texts.

Also on the home page, I have a search bar, in which a user write some keywords, and the results are the texts, that have these keywords

I want to use Semantic Web, and make search bar smarter, with NLP tools like word2vec,

I know how to work with word2vec in a python application only, but I don't know how to make the search bar fully built with python backend, in my Angular Application